# Model test passing when it should not

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created user model using rails create model User name:string email:string, and then i wrote some validation in user.rb (model)

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true
end
```

and simple test to this model

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "John Cena", email: "user@example-domain.de")
  end

  test "should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end

  test "should not be valid" do
    @user.name = ""
    @user.email = ""
    assert_not @user.valid?
  end
end
```

everything was OK but if i commented 1 line of validation in model file test was still passing. Test is failed only if both lines are commented. What should i do to rapair this test? I dont want to make 2 tests from this one.

Comment: I don't understand , what error are u getting on your tests? please paste it

Comment: the problem is beacue i dont get an error, when i should. there are assertion, but it should not be.
when i have
`class User < ApplicationRecord
  validates :name, presence: true
end`
test is still assert, but it should not be, because email is empty

Comment: Maybe it's something with spring caching? try bin/spring stop

Comment: But you're using assert_not in the second test, so why should there be an error? the user is invalid and you're asserting its NOT valid, hence no error

Comment: but user ISNT valid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When testing model validations don't just assert that a model is valid or invalid. It invites false positives and makes it so  your tests need to satisfy the requirements of every validation in the model - adding an attribute or validation means that you need to rewrite the test!

Instead you should verify that the validation exists by looking at the errors object.

```
class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user = User.new
    @user.valid?
    @messages = @user.errors.messages
  end

  test "validates name" do
    assert_includes @messages[:name], "can't be blank"
  end

  test "validates email" do
    assert_includes @messages[:email], "can't be blank"
  end
end
```

Your functional and integration tests will cover the validations as a whole - so your don't need to test that a record is valid if you satisfy all the requirements.